# Win95/98/Me/NT Support in C++

Tags: visual-c++

Which "modern" C++ compilers support Win95/98/Me/NT? VS2010/VS2008 [doesn't support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) these operating systems, so would it be best if I used VS2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2005 is fine as well. The [VS2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) version of your link specifically states that it is the first version to discontinue support:

> Beginning with Visual C++ 2008, Visual C++ does not support targeting Windows 95, Windows 98, Windows ME, or Windows NT. If your WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT macros are assigned to one of these versions of Windows, you will need to modify the macros.

Technically, this has nothing to do with the compiler itself. It just means that you can no longer set the version macros to target an older version of Windows. Again, this doesn't necessarily mean that your program *won't* run on older versions of Windows, it just means that the header declarations aren't backward-compatible with older versions. Your program will still run fine as long it doesn't use any functions that were introduced in Win2K and above.

Of course, it really isn't worth supporting those (broken) operating systems any more.

Comment: There's a difference between broken and unsupported...98 wasn't as broken as ME which was almost as broken as NT. 98SE was pretty decent. My console app which used only string, cout, cin, and endl gives me an error when I try to run it on Windows 98 (OS is unsupported) so I'm not sure what header declaration is incompatible (or if its purposely broken). Anyhow, do you know of a more modern C++ IDE/compiler than VS2005? Or would VS2005 still be the best compiling C++ to Win 95/98?

Comment: @user389823: Indeed Win98 was the best of the lot, nevertheless the entire architecture of Win9x/ME was broken because of MS-DOS compatibility. I believe your error is because the VC++ runtime libraries are not present on that system: try linking with the static libraries (Settings -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library).

Comment: It still gives me an error when I open that it "expects a newer version of Windows. Upgrade your Windows version."

Comment: @user389823: It's possible that the console app runtime specifically doesn't support older versions. Then you probably have to stick with VS2005. I'm guessing Win32 applications should still work properly as long as they don't use the CRT library.

Comment: @Eugene That's probably because you didn't explicitly set the minimum OS version for your application. The linker default has been changed to 5 (Window 2000) with the release of VS2008.